# in my code please help i keep getting : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

```
package Josh_the_bot;

/**
 *
 * @author Jarvis-Main
 */
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Josh_the_bot {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.lang.InterruptedException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO code application logic here 
        Scanner namea = new Scanner (System.in);
        int temperature = 0 ;
        String theName;
        theName = "Josh";
        String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hello What Is Your Name?");
        int namez = Integer.getInteger(name);
        String namereply = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "O hello" + namez );
        int lel = Integer.parseInt(namereply);
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Josh_the_bot.Josh_the_bot.main(Josh_the_bot.java:27)
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: You should paste your code in the question,  and make sure it's formatted   (highlighted and click the curly braces button in the editor).

Comment: `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` might return a `null` if you cancel the dialog, but I'd be more concerned with `int namez = Integer.getInteger(name);` which is likely to fail, as unless the `String` contains nothing but numerical values, it will cause a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: @MadProgrammer How do i make it so it take in "names" im new to java :/ thx

Comment: `Integer.getInteger` doesn't do what I think you want it to do.  It's pulling a `int` property value from the `System.properies` with the specified name or `null` if none exists